# Compile ebtable_broute for DD-WRT

Tags: linux, embedded, compilation, ipv6, router

Recently, I installed a DD-WRT on my router (WNR3500L).
Sadly, I lost the IPv6 compatibility (Netgear's firmware worked like a charm).
My modem is providing native connectivity and announces the prefix.

I was advised to use a bridge only for IPv6.
First, I used a compiled ebtable_broute.o that I found here : http://vibe.ipv6.free.fr/ although my router is running kernel 2.6.24.111 and the module is for 2.4.34.
I could make the bridge, I had IPv6 but from time to time I was losing (few seconds) my IPv4 connection.

So I decided to compile by myself the modules. As a big noob, I followed this guide http://blog.dest-unreach.be/2010/12/01/compiling-custom-dd-wrt-kernel-modules.
At last something was ouputted. I pushed the modules (the .o and the .ko) onto the router (I also uploaded them on http://www.mygb.eu/ddwrt/ebtable_broute.o http://www.mygb.eu/ddwrt/ebtable_broute.ko).
I'm now unable to write "insmod ebtable_broute.o" or "insmod ebtable_broute.ko". (lsmod doesn't displays it and "ebtables -t broute" keep saying that it's not implemented in the kernel.

I also tried without success an IPv6 tunnel with Hurricane Electric. Still nothing.

I'm thinking I could use something with NDP proxy, but the router doesn't have this.

Then I'm becoming to thing I'm IPv6-damned.
Could you help me ?
Thanks in advance